# Wait until i have a specific value in appdata in MATLAB gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, wait, matlab-guide, appdata

I'm working on a `GUI`. I want something likes `waitfor` for `appdata`. For example I use `setappdata(0,'Value',2)` in another window and i want my main `gui` wait and stop to continue the code until this `appdata` exists and the value is equal to `2`.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19011-function-to-wait-for-a-variable-to-change-value) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15460-is-there-a-command-in-matlab-for-waiting)?

Comment: That's good. Please add it to answers Dev-iL.

Comment: I'm happy that you found those helpful, however since these are not my solutions and I can't take credit for them... If any of those worked for you, it would be best if posted your own answer describing your solution in detail (including a _working example_ perhaps?).